# creating a sidebar navigation drawer with a button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a sidebar navigation drawer that slides when a user clicks the button. I'm trying to add this feature into my existing layout and I'm having trouble with it. As you can see in my layout, I have created a menu resource file and included into my main layout but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my main layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"

    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="113dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/item_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/relativeAd"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search_box"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeAd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/divider"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_1"
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton9"
    app:backgroundTint="?attr/actionModeSplitBackground"
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/frameLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center_vertical|right" />
```

Here is my screenshot of my layout

My existing layout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.
This a code for navigation drawer which opens and closes using button and swipe both.

so below is the layout code for setting up navigation drawer.
**xml** file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.whiskey.servicedog.TrainingProgrammes">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_bg"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/White"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/White"

        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

now **java** code for setting up navigation drawer.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id._aboutus:

                Intent aboutusintent = new Intent(TrainingProgrammes.this, AboutUS.class);
                aboutusintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(aboutusintent);
                break;
            case R.id._trainingprog:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Training Programmes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                break;
            case R.id._taskhis:
                Intent historyintent = new Intent(TrainingProgrammes.this, TaskHistory.class);
                historyintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(historyintent);
                break;
            case R.id.taskrem:
                Intent newintent = new Intent(TrainingProgrammes.this, TaskReminders.class);
                newintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(newintent);

                break;
            case R.id.settingschange:
                Intent settingIintent = new Intent(TrainingProgrammes.this, Settings.class);
                settingIintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(settingIintent);

                break;

            case R.id.help_btn:
                Intent helpIintent = new Intent(TrainingProgrammes.this, Help.class);
                helpIintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(helpIintent);

                break;
            case R.id.logout:
                Intent intent = new Intent(TrainingProgrammes.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (preferences.contains("password")) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.remove("password");
                    editor.commit();
                }
                finish(); // Call once you redirect to another activity.


        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you out.
Here is the screenshot of above working code.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use below `xml` to add a `Drawer Layout` and `include` your previous `layout` 
`<include layout="@layout/content_home_page" />` by replacing this

name it `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!--Main Content Goes Here-->
    <include layout="@layout/content_home_page" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
         app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
            android:background="@drawable/side_menu_header_bg">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/user_placeholder" />

                <com.sslwireless.gulshanclub.Fonts.RobotoCondensedBold
                    android:id="@+id/memberFullName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Mr. John Doe"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <com.sslwireless.gulshanclub.Fonts.RobotoCondensedRegular
                    android:id="@+id/memberEmail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="john.doe@mail.com"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In your activity:

```
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

inside your button click listener click event,

call  `drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);`

Comment: So are you suggesting me to create a new layout like you mentioned above and include it into my main layout?

Comment: No! Include your one into my one. 

`<include layout="@layout/YOUR_LAYOUT" />` 

Check my code 11 TH line of xml has this.

Comment: Oh okay, but in the code you mentioned: app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main".    <--- Do I need to create another layout named nav_header_main?

Comment: just create that and paste this ! 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />`

Comment: Okay I'm getting cannot resolve from these lines of code.     android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
            android:background="@drawable/side_menu_header_bg">.          android:src="@drawable/user_placeholder" />

Comment: `@dimen/nav_header_height` replace with `180dp`  rest 2 just use any drawable items from your project as you want